# trying to save a view without it changing my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query below which highlights any differences between two tables which have the same name but are on different databases although on the same server.

It works fine and returns the expected results. I then thought I would save this as view. However when I copy the text into the view it changes the query into the second query below. Why is it doing this? Its rather frustrating.

**My working query**

```
;with t as
(
  select SaleDate, id 
  from MyTbl
  group by SaleDate, id
), r as
(
  select SaleDate, id
  from AnotherDatabase.dbo.MyTbl    
  group by SaleDate, id
)
select coalesce(t.SaleDate, r.SaleDate) SaleDate, t.id [t_cp], 
 r.id [r_cp] 
from t full outer join r on t.SaleDate = r.SaleDate and t.id = 
r.id
where t.id is null or r.id is null
```

**View query**

```
WITH t AS (SELECT        SaleDate, id
                    FROM            dbo.MyTbl
                    GROUP BY SaleDate, id), r AS
(SELECT        SaleDate, id
  FROM            dbo.MyTbl AS MyTbl_1
  GROUP BY SaleDate, id)
SELECT        COALESCE (t_1.SaleDate, r_1.SaleDate) AS SaleDate, t_1.id AS t_cp, r_1.id AS r_cp
 FROM            t AS t_1 FULL OUTER JOIN
                          r AS r_1 ON t_1.pricedate = r_1.pricedate AND t_1.id = r_1.id
 WHERE        (t_1.id IS NULL) OR
                          (r_1.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Is there any difference, except from formatting style?

Comment: Then don't "copy the text into the view" to let Management Studio mangle it. Script it as a `CREATE VIEW` statement; the engine won't change a single character in it. The visual editors are vastly overrated; if you want good support for both GUI editing and script editing, use SSDT.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah ok that sounds better!

Answer (score 0):

i usually use any textpad editor and save the code in .sql . I have never faced this problem

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.